# Creating rollover tooltip for a view (Netflix Style)

Tags: 7, views, tooltips

Here is my scenario: I'm trying to create a view that displays images, and some additional information on rollover -- Something similar to how Netflix does it, and I'm trying to determine the most feasible way to do this. I've found the [Beauty Tips](http://drupal.org/project/beautytips) module, but since my view is inside a panel, I'm not really sure if this module will do exactly what I'm looking for. Any tips on how this could be implemented would be really helpful. (using Drupal 7 btw)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the [Views Tooltip](http://drupal.org/project/views_tooltip) module, which allows you to do exactly that. It depends on the [Tipsy](http://drupal.org/project/tipsy) tooltip module, and works with Drupal 7.